# How to customize a BAD CAPTCHA message in Zend Framework 2 (ZF2)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, captcha

I'm using an Image Captcha and I want to customize the "Captcha value is wrong" error message.

This is the definition of my Captcha:

```
$captcha = new ImageCaptcha();
$font = "./data/fonts/calibri.ttf";
$captcha->setFont($font);
$captcha->setDotNoiseLevel(55);
$captcha->setLineNoiseLevel(3);
```

In my form's constructor:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
    'name' => 'captcha',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Please verify you are human.',
        'captcha' => $this->captcha,
        'messages' => array(
            \Zend\Captcha\Image::BAD_CAPTCHA => 'super neat captcha message.',
        ),
    ),
));
```

I also tried:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
    'name' => 'captcha',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Please verify you are human.',
        'captcha' => $this->captcha,
        'messages' => array(
            \Zend\Captcha\AbstractWord::BAD_CAPTCHA => 'super neat captcha message.',
        ),
    ),
));
```

But I keep getting the "Captcha value is wrong" message.

Answer (score 0):

The "message" part has to be in the captcha-options like this:

```
$this->add([
  'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
  'name' => 'captcha',
  'options' => [
      'label' => 'Please verify you are human.',
      'captcha' => [
          ...
          'messages' => [
             \Zend\Captcha\Image::BAD_CAPTCHA => 'super neat captcha message.',
          ],
      ],   
  ],
]);
```

At least it works for me with Zend Framework 3.

Answer (score -1):

Adding captcha element:

```
   $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
            'name' => 'captcha',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Please verify you are human.',
                'captcha' => $this->captcha            
            ),
        ));
```

And error message:

```
$this->getInputFilter()->get('captcha')->setErrorMessage('super neat captcha message.');
```

It works for me.